# How to get added and removed files using Media scanner or other android API?

Tags: android, media

When we remove or add any file(even text, document or non-media files) on the sdcard in Android (or even after transfering a file on PC though USB mode), media scanner gets started.

I want to know which files are removed or added (in array or one at a time), after media scanner is done or in between

Can it be done using MediaScanner API or other android API? I want to update a list based on the added or removed file(s).

Answer (score 0):

The `MediaScannerConnection`-class has an interface called [MediaScannerConnectionClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient.html), which is notified when a file has been scanned. It returns the URI of the file. You can then read the file or do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks lukas, Does same notify about file removed as well ? It is called for each file added/removed?

Comment: The documentation says it notified when "a file is scanned". You'll have to test it.